# MATLAB - What is the probability of a given number in this matrix being greater than 25?

Tags: matlab, matrix, probability

I am stuck on how to check how many numbers in a 100x100 matrix is greater than 25. Below is the code I have so far:

```
loop = 1:100;
RandomNumbers = normrnd(0, 25, [100, 100]);
NumberCounter = 0;
for i = 1:10000
    if i >= 1
        if (RandomNumbers(loop, 100) > 25)
            NumberCounter = NumberCounter + 1
        elseif (RandomNumbers(100, loop) > 25)
            NumberCounter = NumberCounter + 1
        end
    end
end
```

My NumberCounter variable is not updating...it just stays at zero. Any help is appreciated, along with explanations as to why you did what you did because I want to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let me annotate your code with what it's doing:

```
% This creates a list of numbers, 1 through 100 inclusive
loop = 1:100;
% This generates a 100x100 random matrix drawn from a normal distribution
% with mean 0 and standard deviation 25
RandomNumbers = normrnd(0, 25, [100, 100]);
NumberCounter = 0;
for i = 1:10000
    % This loop only runs over i from 1 to 10000, so i>=1 is always true.
    % This if statement is unnecessary.
    if i >= 1
        % Remember that loop is a _list_ of numbers: RandomNumbers(loop, 100)
        % is the whole 100th column of your random matrix, and so
        % RandomNumbers(loop, 100)>25 is a _list_ of 100 boolean values, 
        % corresponding to whether each element of the 100th column of your matrix
        % is greater than 25. By default, Matlab only treats a list of values as 
        % true if they are _all_ true, so this if-statement almost never evaluates
        % to true.
        if (RandomNumbers(loop, 100) > 25)
            NumberCounter = NumberCounter + 1
        % This test is doing the same thing, but testing the 100th row, instead of
        % the 100th column.
        elseif (RandomNumbers(100, loop) > 25)
            NumberCounter = NumberCounter + 1
        end
    end
end
```

The correct code for what you're trying to do would be:

```
RandomNumbers = normrnd(0, 25, [100, 100]);
NumberCounter = 0;
for i = 1:size(RandomNumbers,1)
    for j = 1:size(RandomNumbers,2)
        if RandomNumbers(i,j) > 25
            NumberCounter = NumberCounter + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Let me also mention that a far faster and more concise way to do what you're trying to do would be the following:

```
RandomNumbers = normrnd(0, 25, [100, 100]);
flatVersion = RandomNumbers(:);
NumberCounter = sum(flatVersion > 25);
```

This works because `RandomNumbers(:)` unrolls the matrix out into a single vector, and because `sum` counts 1 for each true value, and 0 for each false value.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!! Im a little confused as to what you did for these two for loops: for i = 1:size(RandomNumbers,1)
    for j = 1:size(RandomNumbers,2) Could you elaborate please?

Comment: `size(RN, 1)` returns the number of rows in matrix `RN`, and `size(RN, 2)` returns the number of columns. This means `i` loops over all rows, and `j` loops over all columns.

Answer (score 4):

For this problem you don't need to use explicit loops (it is also very slow).

`RandomNumbers > 25` will return a matrix where each element is 1 if the corresponding element in `RandomNumbers` is greater than 25 and 0 otherwise:

```
ans =
 Columns 1 to 34
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1

 .
 .
 .
```

The desired result is then the sum of all elements of this matrix. `sum(RandomNumbers > 25)` will return the sum of each column in the matrix:

```
ans =
 Columns 1 to 26
 45 47 55 54 57 52 55 50 57 52 53 47 53 46 51 49 49 42 50 52 54 37 45 48 53 48
 Columns 27 to 52
 51 50 51 53 49 49 48 43 49 49 53 51 52 45 54 49 53 54 48 48 46 46 49 52 47 52
 Columns 53 to 78
 45 44 43 54 50 49 38 50 54 48 50 39 53 46 54 51 53 49 47 46 44 43 48 56 51 44
 Columns 79 to 100
 47 51 58 58 55 41 49 49 43 48 45 52 52 43 54 51 48 55 54 55 44 47
```

Applying sum on this vector is the result we want. Thus, to check how many numbers in a 100x100 matrix is greater than 25, simply use:

```
sum(sum(RandomNumbers > 25))
```

It is also much, much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over one row which is the row 100, and one column which is column hundred. You're not going over all the elements in the matrix. You need to have a nested `for` loop. One that goes over the rows and another that goes over the rows.

For example:

```
for i = 1:100
    for j = 1:100
        if i >= 1
            if (RandomNumbers(loop(i), loop(j)) > 25)
                NumberCounter = NumberCounter + 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I hope this helps!